# How to package "test helpers"?

Tags: python, pytest, packaging, python-packaging

My application consists of two parts: a reusable library and a "front end".  Both are in different source repositories.  The library’s test suite contains some helpers which I want to use in the front end’s test suite.  But how should I package them?  The tests are written for running them with pytest.

One way would be to move the helpers to the under the main package.  However I don’t think that they belong there.  Large parts of them are there to generate example data and aren’t very useful outside of writing tests.

Some of the test helpers are tested themselves.  It would be nice if, with the solution, there is an "obvious" place to put the tests for them.

Comment: Move helpers to a separate distribution, e.g. `mylib-test-helpers`, add it as test dependency to both library and frontend (`tests_require=['mylib-test-helpers']`).

Comment: @hoefling The helpers depend on the library. Wouldn’t that create a cyclic dependency between `mylib` and `mylib-test-helpers`?

Comment: If you declare an explicit dependency on `mylib` in `mylib-test-helpers`, then yes, you'll get a dependency cycle. But `mylib-test-helpers` doesn't have to require `mylib` to install.

Comment: @hoefling Since `mylib-test-helpers` _in fact_ requires `mylib`, it seems wrong to not declare it.

Comment: Sure, `mylib-test-helpers` won't run without `mylib` installed, but it's not meant for standalone usage anyway. Other than that, you have no other choice than to ship the code with `mylib`.